# How to get the latest file from sftp folder

Tags: linux, file, ssh, sftp, scp

We have sftp folder , we are login using 'sftp user@server'. the sftp folder has many files we need to fetch/download the latest file.

I have question is there a way if we can get the latest file name from sftp folder ? 
and then use get/mget to download it.

I don't have ssh connection to  user@server only i can do sftp. And all this process need to be automated so no manual check.

the sftp folder has some thing like this:

sftp> ls -lrt

```
-rw-------   1 0        0            8744 Apr  4 11:03 A.txt
-rw-------   1 0        0           13282 Apr  4 11:51 B.txt
-rw-------   1 0        0          201329 Apr  5  9:54 C.txt
-rw-------   1 0        0             391 Apr  5 10:17 D.txt
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this to keep synced a local version of the files at the remote directory?  If so, you might be able to get away with `get -a *` in your `sftp` connection. If not, I don't know if there will be a solution without having some pre-agreed upon naming convention with whoever is writing the remote stuff so you can do something like `get *_new` or `get *_20180304*` or what-have-you.

Comment: By getting the latest file, there's a significant risk that file is in the process of being written.  Have you given any thought to how you're going to detect and handle that?

Comment: PFB SERVER='test.com' USER='test' PATH='/path/Test' FILE_PATTERN=test_files DESTINATION_PATH='/test/test_path' 

sftp -b <(echo "ls -1rt $PATH/*$FILE_PATTERN*") $USER@$SERVER | tail -1 | xargs -i bash -c 'sftp -b <(echo "get {} $DESTINATION_PATH") $USER@$SERVER' 

following are issues : 1) Its not recognizing the Destination path and placing the file in Script path where i am running 2) its giving the error for "Missing username". if i change from $user@$server to [$user@]$server then its not recognizing the server .

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. Replace localhost with your remote ip.

```
sftp -b <(echo "ls -1rt") localhost | tail -1 | xargs -i bash -c 'sftp -b <(echo "get {}") localhost'
```

Comment: This works for me: `echo "ls -1rt" | sftp localhost | tail -1 | xargs -I {} echo "get {}" | sftp localhost`

Comment: one more question, if the local host i made it global variable and use it in above command sftp command like $user@$localhost, its not working where if i give the name and local server it works - username@Server_host , any reason the global variable not getting recognized while using as $ ?

Comment: @Cyrus's command works for me with variables also.

Comment: Hi @Cyrus,PFB

SERVER='test.com'
USER='test'
PATH='/path/Test'
FILE_PATTERN=test_files
DESTINATION_PATH='/test/test_path'

sftp -b <(echo "ls -1rt $PATH/*$FILE_PATTERN*") $USER@$SERVER | tail -1 | xargs -i bash -c 'sftp -b <(echo "get {} $DESTINATION_PATH") $USER@$SERVER'

following are issues :

Comment: Hi @Cyrus,PFB

SERVER='test.com'
USER='test'
PATH='/path/Test'
FILE_PATTERN=test_files
DESTINATION_PATH='/test/test_path'

sftp -b <(echo "ls -1rt $PATH/*$FILE_PATTERN*") $USER@$SERVER | tail -1 | xargs -i bash -c 'sftp -b <(echo "get {} $DESTINATION_PATH") $USER@$SERVER'



following are issues :


1) Its not recognizing the Destination path and placing the file in Script path where i am running
2) its giving the error for "Missing username". if i change from $user@$server to [$user@]$server  then its not recognizing the server .

Comment: Sorry for formating

Comment: any suggestion ?